# 'API key from Google exposed' Angular app in github repository

Tags: angular, github, configuration

I use GitHub to share my Angular 7.x source code. My application uses 'Google services', so it needs the API key. I put them in the `environmnent.ts` file.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,

  API_URL: '/api/v1/',
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '<API_KEY>',
    authDomain: '<VALUE1>.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://<VALUE1>.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: '<VALUE1>',
    storageBucket: '<VALUE1>.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '<VALUE2>',
    appId: '<VALUE3>'
  }
};
```

Github sent me a notification about: `Warning: GitGuardian detected an API key from Google`. The meaning is obvious, the solution no.

How can I use the Google services (Firebase and so on) on Angular application without share the key on GitHub repository?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Angular team should provide some mechanism to put it in environment files maybe reading from process.env. You have to take care of it manually during your build phase or post build phase, for now you can update git skip tree for your environment prod file and commit with some junk id. If you are using some CI tool then I have no idea how to accomplish it there maybe write some node file replacements which will scan your dist folder post build and replace `apiKey: XXX` with your apiKey reading from .env files or your environment variables

Comment: you can specify your environment variables inside a Json file (credentails.json), and fetch the key details from that file into your ts file. It is the preferred way of accessing sensitive details.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have not already, revoke the credential, once an API key is exposed on GitHub it is compromised people can (and do) use the GitHub public API to scan all commits for secrets and even if it's deleted someone may have still found it.

Store your secrets in a separate file like `.env` file. I would use `.gitignore` to make sure this file is not included in your commits.

If you want to see the best practices for API's I'd follow the [GitGuardian API best practices document](https://github.com/GitGuardian/APISecurityBestPractices)

If you want to make sure you don't leak any more secrets in the future you can create a free account on [GitGuardian](https://gitguardian.com/), they were the company that actually picked up on your leaked API key. They also give good advice on their dashboard what to do if it happens.